# How to save D3 v4 chart as a picture

Tags: d3.js, charts, export

I have found several examples of how to export a D3 chart and save it as a image, but unfortunately none is working for me.
First of all I'm trying with a very simple version converting this svg and adding it to the DOM:

```
let html = self.svg
        .attr("version", 1.1)
        .attr("xmlns", "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg")
        .node().parentNode.innerHTML;

let imgsrc = 'data:image/svg+xml;base64,' + btoa(html);
    let img = '<img src="' + imgsrc + '">';
    self.D3.select("#svgdataurl").html(img);
```

But I get this error:

[image]

Any idea about what is happening?

Comment: Well the error says you have bogus content in your SVG.  Considering your haven't shown us your SVG, I'm not sure how this question can be answered...  My WAG is that your `.parentNode.innerHTML` is sucking in some HTML behind the `svg` tag.

Comment: Hi! thanks for your response, the problem was clear.
I had another element sharing the same container with the SVG, and that was causing the problem.
In the other hand i have had to include the styles in the D3 objects instead using css classes to keep the styles in the generated image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was clear. I had another element sharing the same container with the SVG, and that was causing the problem. In the other hand i have had to include the styles in the D3 objects creation instead using css classes to keep the styles in the generated and exportable image.